# Should be easy jQuery loop, but can't seem to figure out how to cycle through this

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops

I'm building a feature on a website that shows a new "featured counselor" every 5 seconds or so. If it was just showing one pic I would just use show() & hide(). Unfortunately I have to move the image out & then display a div with some caption text, and then after 5 seconds, remove the caption & the image. Fortunately I have successfully written the "show" function, and the "hide" function, AND I've even gotten it to wait the specified 5 seconds before hiding. My problem is that I can't figure out how to move to the next "featured counselor" and run the show-wait-hide functions. Any suggestions would be greatly appreaciate. Here's my code for reference:

CSS:

```
article[role=main] aside li {/*Set up the basic stying & hide them all*/
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   display: none;
  }

article[role=main] aside li.show { /*Only show one at a time*/
display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="items">
<li class="show">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="caption">
          <h5>Featured Counselor</h5>
            <h3>Courtney Humphrey</h3>
            <h4>Registered Dietician</h4>
        </div><!-- End #caption -->
        <div class="featured-counselor">
            <img src="img/featured_counselor_placeholder.jpg" />
        </div><!-- End #featured-counselor -->
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="caption">
          <h5>Featured Counselor</h5>
            <h3>Test Two Title</h3>
            <h4>Registered Dietician</h4>
        </div><!-- End #caption -->
        <div class="featured-counselor">
            <img src="img/featured_counselor_placeholder.jpg" />
        </div><!-- End #featured-counselor -->
    </a>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
featuredCounselorCarousel(); //Call the function that runs the show

function featuredCounselorCarousel() {
    showCurrentCounselor(); //Show the Counselor First
    setTimeout(function() { //Add a timer (Show for 5 seconds)        
    hideCurrentCounselor() //After 5 seconds, hide the current counselor                    
    }, 5000)
}// End featuredCounselorCarousel


function showCurrentCounselor() { //This is the Function that shows the Counselor       
    $('article[role=main] aside ul li.show #featured-counselor').delay( 100 ).animate({"left": "0px"}, 900, 'easeInOutQuint');//Slide out
    $('article[role=main] aside ul li.show #caption').delay( 1000 ).fadeIn(400);//Display the Caption
}// End showCurrentCounselor 


function hideCurrentCounselor() { //This is the Function that hides the Counselor       
    $('article[role=main] aside ul li.show #featured-counselor').delay( 100 ).animate({"left": "-230px"}, 900, 'easeInOutQuint');//Slide Back In
    $('article[role=main] aside ul li.show #caption').delay( 500 ).fadeOut(400);//Remove the Caption
}// End hideCurrentCounselor
```

Comment: Note that your html is invalid: the id attribute is supposed to be unique on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function triggerCarousal(){  setTimeout(function() { //Add a timer (Show for 5 seconds)        
     featuredCounselorCarousel();                    
    }, 5000) }

function featuredCounselorCarousel() {
    hideCurrentCounselor();
showCurrentCounselor(); //Show the Counselor First

}// End featuredCounselorCarousel


function showCurrentCounselor() { //This is the Function that shows the Counselor       
    $('article[role=main] aside ul li.show #featured-counselor').delay( 100 ).animate({"left": "0px"}, 900, 'easeInOutQuint');//Slide out
    $('article[role=main] aside ul li.show #caption').delay( 1000 ).fadeIn(400);//Display the Caption
}// End showCurrentCounselor 


function hideCurrentCounselor() { //This is the Function that hides the Counselor       
    $('article[role=main] aside ul li.show #featured-counselor').delay( 100 ).animate({"left": "-230px"}, 900, 'easeInOutQuint');//Slide Back In
    $('article[role=main] aside ul li.show #caption').delay( 500 ).fadeOut(400);//Remove the Caption
current = $('article[role=main] aside ul li.show');
next = $(current).next();
$(next).toggleClass("show");
$(current).toggleClass("show);
}// End hideCurrentCounselor
```

This might work..

Comment: I really appreciate your help, however this code waits for 5 seconds & then executes

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although I didn't use all of the code you provided, I did use the very last portion that sets "Next" & "Current." You got me pointed in the right direction & I got it all working now. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(#items li).each` inside your `featuredCounselorCarousel` function and all your code goes inside the each.

You will be able to access the current li and can modify your selector in the show and hide function accordingly to be relative to the li element.

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion, but I can't get the timer in the right spot. It keeps firing them all at the same time